# ListView null pointer exception

Tags: android, exception, null, adapter

I have two classes. The first creates an arraylist and an adapter.
Then passes the adapter to an other class to create the ListView. 
The problem is that the Listview says it is null. any idea why?

Class 1:

```
    package com.example.seth.greekproducts;

import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Builder alert;
    EditText etName;
    EditText etCode;
    String name;
    String code;
    ArrayList<String> resultslist;
    Results results;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editname);
        etCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editcode);

        Button bSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSearch);
        bSearch.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button bAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        bAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

        resultslist = new ArrayList<String>();

        results = new Results();

        db=openOrCreateDatabase("ProductsDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products(name VARCHAR, code VARCHAR);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bSearch:
                name = etName.getText().toString();
                code = etCode.getText().toString();
                Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM products WHERE code = '" + code + "'", null);

                if(c.moveToFirst())
                {
                    //etName.setText(c.getString(1));
                    //etCode.setText(c.getString(3));

                    resultslist.add(c.getString(0));
                    resultslist.add(c.getString(1));
                    resultslist.add(c.getString(1));
                    resultslist.add(c.getString(1));

                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, resultslist);

                    etName.setText(adapter.getItem(0).toString());
                    etCode.setText(adapter.getItem(1).toString());

                    results.showResults(adapter);

                    startActivity(new Intent(this, Results.class));
                }
                else
                {
                    showInfo("Σφάλμα", "Δεν Βρέθηκε Αποτέλεσμα!");

                }
                break;


        }
    }

    public void showInfo(String title, String msg){
        alert = new Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setMessage(msg);
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Class 2

```
    package com.example.seth.greekproducts;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class Results extends AppCompatActivity{


    ListView list;




    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);

        list = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.listView );
    }
    public void showResults(ArrayAdapter adapter){
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        System.out.println("Called!");
    }}
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

at Line:

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Activity_Results XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.seth.greekproducts.Results">


        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where did you init adapter?

Comment: You probably having issues referncing the ListView, can you post your XML?

Comment: R.layout.activity_results to be specific

Comment: intialize your `adapter`

Comment: @DanielZolnai Added XML

Comment: @Mohit I cant initialize it. It gets a value when it is being called from the first class.

Comment: Pass your `arrayList` rather than your adapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your problem is that you are creating an activity with a constructor, like this:

```
results = new Results();
```

This won't work, you should always create activities using an `Intent` and `startActivity(...)`, like you did a bit later in your code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Results.class));
```

I also recommend the name suffix `Activity` for activities, so `ResultsActivity` in your case.

The main problem you will have is that you can't easily send data to your activity, because you don't have a reference to it.

You can send objects using your Intent the activity is created with.
You have the `List<String> resultsList`, which you want to pass onto the `ResultsActivity`. Do this by creating the activity with this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultsActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("results", (ArrayList<String>) resultsList);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now modify your `ResultsActivity` that it can take these results:

```
public class ResultsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView list;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayList<String> resultsList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("results");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow, resultslist);
        showResults(adapter);
    }

    public void showResults(ArrayAdapter adapter){
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        System.out.println("Called!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Love this part `suffix Activity for activities`. Really important because your code becomes much more readable.

Comment: Make sure you put those 3 lines in place of your                     `                    
`results.showResults(adapter);startActivity(new Intent(this, Results.class));`
So after `etCode.setText(adapter.getItem(1).toString());`

Comment: @Maloubobola Should do it whenever a class is extended IMO. SomethingFragment, SomethingAdapter etc.

Comment: Exactly. Also don't use misleading names. Like LoginService for an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You called the `showResults` method before starting your activity

```
results.showResults(adapter);
startActivity(new Intent(this, Results.class));
```

so your `list` is null. You must do it after.

But the main problem is that you create a instance of an activity manually. See @Blackbelt answer

Comment: Because `Results` is an activity, you must not use `ǹew`. So my answer will not work, see Daniel Zolnai's one.

Answer (score 0):

Activity work independent from each other. If you will call one of method of Activity into another you have to make sure that, first activity is running unless it will give you nullpointer.

So rather then sending adapter using method, Use Intent.putExtra to send data to another activity and initialize adapter there to show data in second activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Results.class );
i.putExtra("","");//put data to send to Results.class
startActivity(i);
```

in `Result.class`'s onCreate method:

```
Intent i =getIntent();
Object obj=i.getExtra(""); // Change Object with your Parameter type
```

Second Method:

You can try to startActivity without sending any data from database and when you start Result Activity you can get data from database then show it into listview.

I recommended second solution as it will make you easy to code.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it! :)

Comment: I did a variation of your answer and Daniel's. It works now! thanks! :)